# playing video in aspx page

Tags: c#, video, visual-studio-2012, webforms

i'm using video tag to play videos in my project and i want it to play mp4 only. it plays the in chrome with a bit of lag but not in ie or firefox. i'm wondering if there's a simple fix or it's better to embed vlc player.

```
<video id='myVideo' class="video"  controls ="controls" width="600" height="500" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto">
            <source runat="server" id='vidSource' type='video/mp4' visible="False">
        </video>
```

and in the back end i set the src for the source.

```
vidSource.Visible = true;
vidSource.Src = "videos/" + fileName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html5 video is a new thing, and it's not widely and completely supported in all browsers.  Some information on the subject can be found on this page, and in this table here you can see browser compatibility chart:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support

Maybe you could use FlowPlayer or something like it?  What about embedding youtube?

Comment: i'm trying to play uploaded videos by the user.